# Flurry SDKs, How can I get older version of Flurry SDKs?

Tags: iphone, sdk, flurry

Flurry SDKs, now I can only get the sdk 3.0, How can I get older version of Flurry SDKs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me quote you their FAQ: "Please email support if you need to use older versions of the Flurry SDK".